# jQuery Event listeners sticking/cascading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web app, I have a screen that expects a user to use a bar-code scanner to scan an item number in, but in the event they do not have one (or the code won't scan) they can click on the notification that asks them to scan and it changes to a box allowing them to enter the details to search manually.

The issue is, the event listener seems to get applied to the close button, it gets removed from the div but the close button seems to call the "open search box" function instead of the "close search box" function

I tried using the jQuery `$('#id').one('click' function(){myFunctionHere();});` function to add an event listener on click of the DIV and also tried using `$('#id').on('click' function(){myFunctionHere();});` and `$('#id').off('click');` but I have the same issue.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7npzsx6/1/)

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
#tnt-searchScan{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px dashed red;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tnt-searchScan').one('click', function(){showSearchBox();});
})

function closeSearchBox(){
  var html = '<h4>Scan barcode</h4><h4>or click here to search</h4>';
  $('#tnt-searchScan').html(html).one('click', function(){showSearchBox();});
}

function showSearchBox(){
  console.log('test');
  var html = 'Content of search box<button type="button" id="tnt-closeSearchBox">Close</button>';
  $('#tnt-searchScan').html(html);
  $('#tnt-closeSearchBox').one('click', function(){closeSearchBox();});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tnt-searchScan"><h4>Scan barcode</h4><h4>or click here to search</h4></div><div id="tnt-mainPage"><div class="loader"></div> </div>
</body>
```

I expect the box to return back to normal, but it does not, if you check the console, every time you click 'Close' "test" appears, signalling that the show function is called. if i call the "closeSearchBox();" manually it works fine.

Comment: first i see `$('#tnt-searchScan').html(html).one('click',...` has to be `.on('click', ...`

Comment: and `$('#tnt-closeSearchBox').one('click', function(){closeSearchBox();});` can be `$('tnt-closeSearchBox').one('click', closeSearchBox);` but this is just a nice to have.

Comment: @mtizziani i have tried .on and .off (noted in my queation) with the same resault, .one() is the same as .on() but only fires once, so no need for .off()

Comment: ok, i see. have you tried to bind your click listener directly to the buttons? `$('#x').html('<button id="y">')` gives back a representation `<div id="x">` and not `<button id="y">`. and i think there is the problem

Comment: how do you mean? `$('#x').html('<button id="y">');` modifies the DOM and sets the content of `<div id="x"></div>` to `<button id="y">`. I have tried setting the onclick in the html of the close button but still had the issue. I cannot set the HTML onclick of the DIV as the div should not remain clickable after the contents change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your js. First of all `.one` is changed to `.on` second need to change the close function click event because the search form is added with js to dom so you need to fire click event on it like this `$(document).on('click','#tnt-closeSearchBox', function(){ closeSearchBox(); });`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tnt-searchScan').on('click', function(){showSearchBox();});
})

function closeSearchBox(){
  var html = '<h4>Scan barcode</h4><h4>or click here to search</h4>';
  $('#tnt-searchScan').html(html).on('click', function(){showSearchBox();});
}

function showSearchBox(){
  //console.log('test');
  var html = '<label>Search By: <select id="tnt-searchOption">' +
      '<option selected>ID</option>' +
      '<option>Legacy ID</option>' +
      '</select></label>' +
      '<label>Search: <input type="text" id="tnt-searchBox"></label>' +
      '<button type="button">Search</button><button type="button" id="tnt-closeSearchBox">Close</button>';
  $('#tnt-searchScan').html(html);
}
  $(document).on('click','#tnt-closeSearchBox', function(){closeSearchBox();});
```

```css
#tnt-searchScan{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px dashed red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tnt-searchScan"><h4>Scan barcode</h4><h4>or click here to search</h4></div><div id="tnt-mainPage"><div class="loader"></div> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is `.one` changed to `.on`? I would then need to use a `.off` to turn off the function so it does not reset the form every time the form is clicked/tapped, this seems like the exact use case `.one` is intended for.

Comment: Ok, i have modified it a bit, altered the `.one`'s to `.on`'s also added in the `.off`'s so as not to reset the form every click. It did work modifying the `.one('click', '#id', function(){});` but decided against using it as if for some reason the function does not work the first time, the user can just click a second time to retry.